# Heap Size error in jmeter

Tags: java, jmeter

When i trigger a job in jenkins for a jmeter test with 3000 user count i get below exception in jmeter-server.log file

```
2018-05-16 15:26:45,696 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.jmeter.testbeans.gui.GenericTestBeanCustomizer

at org.apache.jmeter.testbeans.BeanInfoSupport.createPropertyGroup(BeanInfoSupport.java:255) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]

at org.apache.jmeter.config.CSVDataSetBeanInfo.<init>(CSVDataSetBeanInfo.java:58) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:4.0 r1823414]

at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_25]

at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]

at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]

at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]

at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at com.sun.beans.finder.InstanceFinder.instantiate(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]

    at com.sun.beans.finder.InstanceFinder.find(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]

at java.beans.Introspector.findExplicitBeanInfo(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]

at java.beans.Introspector.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]

at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]

at org.apache.jmeter.testbeans.TestBeanHelper.prepare(TestBeanHelper.java:66) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]

at org.apache.jmeter.threads.TestCompiler.trackIterationListeners(TestCompiler.java:183) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]

at org.apache.jmeter.threads.TestCompiler.subtractNode(TestCompiler.java:137) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]

at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:998) ~[jorphan.jar:4.0 r1823414]

at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:995) ~[jorphan.jar:4.0 r1823414]

at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:977) ~[jorphan.jar:4.0 r1823414]

at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.initRun(JMeterThread.java:611) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]

at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:246) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]

at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
2018-05-16 15:26:45,712 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Users 1-1157
2018-05-16 15:26:45,712 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.jmeter.testbeans.gui.GenericTestBeanCustomizer

at org.apache.jmeter.testbeans.BeanInfoSupport.createPropertyGroup(BeanInfoSupport.java:255) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]

at org.apache.jmeter.config.CSVDataSetBeanInfo.<init>(CSVDataSetBeanInfo.java:58) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:4.0 r1823414]

at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_25]

at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]

at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]

at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]

at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at com.sun.beans.finder.InstanceFinder.instantiate(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]

    at com.sun.beans.finder.InstanceFinder.find(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]

at java.beans.Introspector.findExplicitBeanInfo(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]

at java.beans.Introspector.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]

at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]

at org.apache.jmeter.testbeans.TestBeanHelper.prepare(TestBeanHelper.java:66) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]

at org.apache.jmeter.threads.TestCompiler.trackIterationListeners(TestCompiler.java:183) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]

    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.TestCompiler.subtractNode(TestCompiler.java:137) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]

at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:998) ~[jorphan.jar:4.0 r1823414]

at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:995) ~[jorphan.jar:4.0 r1823414]

    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:977) ~[jorphan.jar:4.0 r1823414]

at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.initRun(JMeterThread.java:611) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]

at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:246) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]

at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
2018-05-16 15:26:45,790 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception: 
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin\awt.dll: ”ÛH`ÚH¼ÖH—‹„G¶

at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_25]

at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]

at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]

at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]

at java.awt.Toolkit$3.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.Toolkit$3.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]

at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_25]

at java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]

at java.awt.Component.<clinit>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]

at org.apache.jmeter.testbeans.BeanInfoSupport.createPropertyGroup(BeanInfoSupport.java:255) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]

at org.apache.jmeter.config.CSVDataSetBeanInfo.<init>(CSVDataSetBeanInfo.java:58) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:4.0 r1823414]

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_25]

at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]

at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]

at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]

at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]

at com.sun.beans.finder.InstanceFinder.instantiate(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]

at com.sun.beans.finder.InstanceFinder.find(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]

at java.beans.Introspector.findExplicitBeanInfo(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]

at java.beans.Introspector.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]

at org.apache.jmeter.testbeans.TestBeanHelper.prepare(TestBeanHelper.java:66) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]

at org.apache.jmeter.threads.TestCompiler.trackIterationListeners(TestCompiler.java:183) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]

at org.apache.jmeter.threads.TestCompiler.subtractNode(TestCompiler.java:137) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]

at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:998) ~[jorphan.jar:4.0 r1823414]

at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:995) ~[jorphan.jar:4.0 r1823414]

at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:977) ~[jorphan.jar:4.0 r1823414]

at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.initRun(JMeterThread.java:611) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]

at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:246) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]

at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
2018-05-16 15:26:45,805 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Users 1-990
2018-05-16 15:26:45,805 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception:
```

I am running the test in a remote machine. Also i want to run the test for 50000 user count.How shall i set heap size for this through jenkins

Also i am getting java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin\awt.dll exception

Answer (score 1):

Your Java installation seems to be broken.

Reinstall it (a jdk would be better) and try again.

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_25\
                 ^^^^
```

I strongly doubt you will be able to reach 50 000 (or even 3000) virtual users with 32-bit JRE. According to [Oracle documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#gc_heap_32bit)

> On most modern 32-bit Windows systems the maximum heap size will range from 1.4G to 1.6G.

So consider migrating to [64-bit Server JRE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase8-2177648.html) as soon as possible and adjust HEAP size to be around 80% of your total available physical RAM. Also make sure you're following other recommendations from the [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) guide.

Also 50 000 virtual users doesn't seem something you will be able to kick off on a single machine, most probably you will have to go for [Distributed Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html).